# change user agent stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I want to change the style of a page, when I check in developer tools, I see the style but no the file where it comes from, **only user agent stylesheet** and I don't know how to change the color

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);
    background-image: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: User agent stylesheets are built-in to the browser. You can change your own but you can't change them for others that visit a site. For that you'd need to either put the styling in a `<style>` block in the page, or create a separate stylesheet and link to it from the page.

Comment: Honestly your question is not clear to me

Comment: Have you tried to add these styles yourself to your own css file?

Comment: According to https://superuser.com/q/594358/74576 it's no longer possible.